# How to fix XCode code folding visual bug?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos-big-sur

XCode 12.5 code folding is visually bugged for **functions**, **if** / **while** statements and multiline **comments**. It looks like this:

[image: A gif to illustrate]

I must mention, that this is a completely clean single-app project, I'm using XCode that was installed 10 minutes ago, no plugins, no 3rd party tools.

I have already cleaned DerivedData for like 100 times, uninstall XCode twice. I don' really understand why I get the same bug after reinstalling the IDE. Did I miss deleting some XCode cache?

Comment: My money is on it being a for-real bug. Apple's quality control isn't great with their developer tools. If a bug doesn't prevent their engineering team from building their products, it doesn't get much attention.

Comment: Agree with @DuncanC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually disappears when I downgraded Xcode to 12.4.
I was hoping that this bug is only relative to Big Sur + Xcode 12.5, but unfortunately macOS 12 beta and Xcode 13 beta are just as broken.

The suitable workaround is to keep 2 versions of Xcode installed. 12.4 for the actual development, 12.5 or later for debugging applications on the device. For me it's Xcode 13 beta that I use to run on my iPhone with iOS 15.

Comment: upd: this [link](https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d) will explain how to build applications for iOS 15 device using Xcode 12